# Symmetries and conservation laws for a falling cat

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, conservation-laws, symmetry, noethers-theorem

For Hamiltonian systems, symmetries and conservation laws are defined and related to each other by Noether's theorem. Symmetry means the invariance of the Hamiltonian for a transformation group, and the notion of momentum and angular momentum is also defined by the use of the Hamiltonian.

Cats are highly non-hamiltonian (and non-lagrangian) systems, yet in a free falling and rotation-free reference system, they also obey the law of conservation of momentum and angular momentum when they are in free fall. In this case, momentum and angular momentum aren't related to any Hamiltonian, Lagrangian or potential, they are simply the quantities which are used by Newton. Of course, the conservation of momentum and angular momentum can be derived from Newton's laws (if we suppose that all forces are central), but this derivation doesn't provide the relation between symmetries and conservation laws.

My question:

1. How can *symmetry* be defined for a non-hamiltonian (and non-lagrangian) system (like a cat)?
2. How can we relate symmetries to conservation laws in these systems?

Comment: https://youtube.com/watch?v=RtWbpyjJqrU

Comment: Newtonian mechanics is a very special case of Lagrangian mechanics when you decide to define $L=\frac{1}{2}mv^2-U$. Therefore, if it works in Newton's method, it definitely works with Lagrange's method.

Comment: It is Hamiltonian, it is just that it is extremely complex to write due to the enormous number of particles

Comment: I'll admit I haven't looked into it deeply, but can't a falling cat be modeled by a Lagrangian and a set of nonholonomic constraints?  In such cases, it seems obvious how to define a symmetry (a transformation that preserves the Lagrangian and the constraints), though I don't know how or whether Noether's Theorem can be extended to such cases.

Comment: Oh hey, this seems to be on point: F. Fassò & N. Sansonetto, ["An Elemental Overview of the Nonholonomic Noether Theorem"](https://www.math.unipd.it/~fasso/research/papers/nnt2.pdf), Int. J. Geom. Meth. Mod. Phys. **8**, 1343–1355 (2009).

Comment: Things get a bit weird when cats don't know which way "up" is.  See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O9XtK6R1QAk